# Can I specify a .zip format for a .sql file created from Windows At.exe?

Tags: mysql, database-backups, at-job

I have automated my mySQL db backup on my Windows 2003 server using AT.exe.  I have scheduled a job like this, which is working fine.

```
AT 23:59 /EVERY:m,t,w,th,f,s,su c:\path\backup.bat
```

In the backup.bat file, is this line

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.20\bin\mysqldump -u username -ppassword --result-file="c:\automatedDBBackups\backup.%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%.sql" dbname
```

I would like to specify a compression format for the output file.

Comment: You can use command-line buckup feature (with compression option) in dbForge Studio for MySQL - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/mysql-backup.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything built into mysqldump, but what you can do is chain a pipe command out to do a zip, after it's complete. Here's an example by using 7-zip's command line.

```
mysqldump blah blah ... | path/to/7zip/7za a > /path/to/backup/backup.dbname.gz
```

You should probably put 7za.exe into your PATH environment variable. You can see the full list of the command line options and switches [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make mysqldump's output as a zip file. You need to install 3rd party command-line zip tools.